# CSS, centralizar linha separatoria entre left e right

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu possuo uma div, `welcome-inputs` e dentro dela outras duas `left` e `right`

A `left` precisa estar do lado esquerdo da `welcome-inputs` e a `right` do lado direito da `welcome-inputs`.

Ambas tem `width = 100px`

Preciso por uma linha que fique no **meio** das duas, sinalizando a separação.

Vejam o codigo [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gn1asdmh/3/).

A linha em vermelho precisa estar no meio das imagens (que representam left e right)

Comment: A tua edição mudou radicalmente a solução adequada para lidar com o teu problema...

Comment: Se ao menos você explicar qual o problema com as respostas dadas, podemos tentar melhorar.

Comment: @Bacco, você que respondeu abaixo, isto aqui parece mais uma pergunta camaleão que precisa de *Rollback* (v3?) do que ser fechada, não?

Comment: @brasofilo ai não sei se bagunça a do Renan. Talvez seja o caso de fechar e depois quem sabe ela acabe sumindo...

Comment: Caro User 3163662, por favor, não mude ***radicalmente*** sua pergunta depois de obter respostas ao problema inicial. Desse jeito, você presta um desserviço ao site e aos colegas que tomaram tempo em responder à primeira versão. Por favor, confira [O que fazer quando o O.P muda sua pergunta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1682/201)

Answer (score 5):

Um exemplo simples de como por uma linha no meio, usando `border`:

```css
div {
  position:relative;      /* Uma espécie de "reset" para os divs se comportarem bem */
  box-sizing:border-box;  /* Ajuste para que o padding não atrapalhe a medida dos 50% */
  padding: 10px;          /* Mera estética da demonstração */
}

.main {
  width: 80%;             /* acrescentei isto baseado no edit da questão e comments*/
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.left {
  float:left;             /* Fixamos a div na esquerda */
  clear:both;             /* Forçamos ela a começar em nova linha, caso haja mais divs */
  width:50%;              /* E ajustamos a largura. */
}

.right {
  margin-left:50%;             /* Aqui usamos a margem em vez de float right */
  border-left: 1px dashed white; /* e colocamos a linha separadora */
}

html, body {      /* Daqui pra baixo é só reset e estética do teste. */
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">1</div>
  <div class="right">2</div>
</div>
```

Tem outras maneiras de fazer, mas sem mais detalhes na pergunta, ficariamos o dia todo testando alternativas.

Comment: editei a pergunta, acho que esclareci.

Comment: @user3163662 atualizei a resposta, execute em "pagina toda" pra ver se é mais ou menos isso, e mude a janela do browser pra ver o tamanho quando encolhe a pagina.

Comment: veja este http://jsfiddle.net/gn1asdmh/ ele é mei codigo, porem a linha nao fica no meio..

Comment: Já tinha visto seu código, do jeito que vc montou a estrutura fica complicado de usar. Melhor não complicar tanto. Você aproveitou o que eu fiz, mas enfiou o float-right lá de novo... ai não vai mesmo. Como eu disse no comentário que fiz na resposta, sem saber melhor o que vai em cada parte das divs, e como é pra ficar o resultado final, fica dificil saber o melhor caminho.

Answer (score 2):

Uma solução passa por fazer uso da propriedade de CSS [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) onde podemos indicar que queremos que a largura dos elementos inclua `padding` e `border`:

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

Desta forma, podemos dar uma borda a um dos elementos e visualmente é impercetível o desfasamento microscópico que efetivamente existe.

De igual forma, os elementos estão sempre a ocupar 50% da largura do seu elemento pai:

```css
body {
    background:blue;
}
.left{
    float:left;
    border-right:1px dotted white;
}
.right{
    float:right;
}
.welcomeforms{
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:50%;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="welcome-inputs">

    <div class="welcomeforms left">left</div>
    <div class="welcomeforms right">right</div>

</div>
```

---

Exemplo também no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/ku9awwo0/).

Comment: editei a pergunta, acho que esclareci.

Answer (score 2):

Podem existir propostas melhores que sejam <s>sem gambiarras</s> mais elegantes. Uma ideia consiste basicamente em inserir um elemento `<span>` entre suas `<divs> .left` e `.right`, algo como se fosse um separador.

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0} /*reset*/

.welcome {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    background: blue
}

.left, .right { position: absolute }

.left { left: 0 }
.right{ right: 0 }

.left > img, .right > img { width: 100px } /* tamanho das imagens */

.separator {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0; bottom: 0;
    
    width: 5%;
    left: 47.5%; /* 50% (metade) - 5%(largura do separador) */
    max-width: 10px; /* para evitar que ele aumente conforme a porcentagem de largura que é 5% */
  
    background: red
}
```

```html
<div class='welcome'>
    <div class='left'>
        <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmii1.jpg' alt=''/>
    </div>
    <span class='separator'></span>
    <div class='right'>
        <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmii1.jpg' alt=''/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Eu acho que a sua resposta resolve bem para a **[versão atual da pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/44140/revisions)**. Agora é só torcer para não mudar tudo de novo :)

Comment: @Bacco e renan  Obrigado pela ajuda, desculpe se de alguma forma deixei confusa a pergunta é atrapalhei o esclarecimento correto, me ajudou muito, vlw..

Comment: @Bacco continuei sem entender o que ele realmente queria.

Comment: @renan mistérios... o mundo é cheio de mistérios... :D